# Sort ObservableCollection by Date

Tags: c#

I have a collection

```
private ObservableCollection<ContentItemViewModel> _contentTree;
        public ObservableCollection<ContentItemViewModel> ContentTree
        {
            get { return _contentTree; }
        }
```

class ContentItemViewModel has property:

```
 private string _published;
        public string Published
        {
            get
            {
                return _published;
            }
            set
            {
                _published = value;

                NotifyPropertyChanged("Published");
            }
        }
```

that is -  `node.Published= Convert.ToDateTime(date.Value).ToString("dd MMM yyyy", new DateTimeFormatInfo());`

I need to sort ContentTree collection by date? how can I do this?

Comment: Does sorted collection need to be observable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not know if there is any better way but you can do the following. The idea here is to create an ordered list and first foreach item in the ordered list, removing and re-adding the related item from content tree.

```
var tempList = _contentTree.OrderBy(p => DateTime.Parse(p.DateAndTime)); 

tempList.ToList().ForEach(q =>
            {
                _contentTree.Remove(q);
                _contentTree.Add(q);
            });
```

Or you can employ Comparison;

```
Comparison<ContentItemViewModel> comparison = new Comparison<ContentItemViewModel>(
            (p,q) =>
            {
                DateTime first = DateTime.Parse(p.DateAndTime);
                DateTime second = DateTime.Parse(q.DateAndTime);
                if (first == second)
                    return 0;
                if (first > second)
                    return 1;
                return -1;
            });


        List<ContentItemViewModel> tempList = _contentTree.ToList();
        tempList.Sort(comparison);
        _contentTree = new ObservableCollection<ContentItemViewModel>(tempList);
```

Comment: so at first it should sort by date from the last to first. If there is some elements with tha same date it shoul sort by the index in contentTree collection

Comment: Then you can use comparison, just change the comparison with the way you want.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this:

```
ConceptItems = new ObservableCollection<DataConcept>(ConceptItems.OrderBy(i => i.DateColumn));
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Change it to list `ToList();`
2. Sort it using OrderBy or...
3. Make a new `ObservableCollection` using that list.